# How to find duplicate values across two columns in excel, regardless of the row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to highlight cells in column A and column B where the cell in column A matches any cell in column B. Cell contents are strings, not numbers.

[image]

Comment: Use Conditional Formatting

Comment: I don't know the formula ... Trying to figure that out.

Comment: Most of the online tutorials just show how to look for a match across columns for two cells that are on the same row ...

Comment: Picture added for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two Conditional Formatting rules, one for Column A and the other for Column B

Column A:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,B:B,0))
```

Column B:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1,A:A,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I should have specified, the numbers in my example don't represent what's in my actual spreadsheet. I have email addresses.

Comment: @Abram does not matter, the MATCH if one is found will return a number.

Comment: Any chance you can expand the rule in the conditional formatting rules manager. The Applies to part is confusing me, and I'm afraid I have it backwards.

Comment: Column B formula applies to `=$B:$B` and the other to the other.

Comment: Thanks so much Scott. I'm new to this.

Comment: You can use one formula if you want @ScottCraner, just an idea to use: `=COUNTIF($A:$B;A1)>1` on selected range.

Comment: @JvdV unless there is duplicates in the columns themselves.

Comment: @JvdV and countif is slower than Match.

Comment: Really, I only needed to check a column of emails against another column of emails for dupes, so I only needed Scott's formula once to identify the dupes in my sheet.

Comment: That's very true :) @ScottCraner, you awefully good at these things (in a good way)